# Implementing ImageSwitcher Functionality | FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, universal-image-loader

I am trying to implement ImageSwitcher functionality using the Android-Universal-Image-Loader,
Below is the code,

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrls[position]);

            System.out.println("URI=" + uri);
         InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            **inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);**
            Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            i.setImageBitmap(bm);
            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

But ,I get the `FileNotFoundException` at:

```
inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

But when I try accessing the URI directly from the web browser, I see the image. The Image URI are set this way:

```
public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {

    "http://image.donga.com/mlbpark/fileUpload/201401/52dde15113c53b01da3b.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg",
    etc...
```

Any idea where am I going wrong?